# Python3 upload to AWS WorkDocs

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-workdocs

Does anyone have example code for an upload to WorkDocs with Python? The quickstart guide [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-workdocs-dev-guide/blob/master/doc_source/upload-documents.md) says I should be able to PUT with a "Content-Type","application/octet-stream," but

```
r= requests.put(url, upfile)
upfile={'file': ('file.pdf', open('file.pdf', 'rb'), 'application/octet-
stream')}
```

produces an error beginning:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we 
calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and 
signing method.</Message> ...
```

I see that the quickstart suggests properties of "x-amz-server-side-encryption", "AES256".  How do I set those in requests? Do I need some other library?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured it out: when you InitiateDocumentVersionUpload, WorkDocs wants you to feed back the headers and signed key given in the response.

I was thinking Boto would use my IAM keys to encrypt the response, and prove that I am an authorized user.  But that's overthinking it.  WorkDocs expects you to mimic the headers, including the signed key given to you.